# Display a subform on clicked button - LOTUS NOTES 6.5

Tags: button, lotus-notes, subform

I'm new in programming in Lotus and I have a 'problem'. I would appreciate if you would help me. : - )

So, I create a button on a form ( called Form3 ), the button name is Click. All I want to do is when I click the button a subform will appear. I created the subform and I called it Subform3. I guess i have to code in the button's method called: Click. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the subform3 to your form3
2. Add a button to Form3 to control showing the subform
3. Set the button's formula to toggle a value to a variable:
   FIELD SubformToggle := @If(SubformToggle = 1; 0; 1);
4. Set the HideWhen formula for the subform to be SubformToggle = 0

Comment: Many thanks, dear sir Ken! But when I open the info-box dialog properties for Subform, I can not see a "HideWhen" formula

Comment: Hide when formulas are on the properties of the paragraphs in your subform.  The best idea is to create a hidden field at the top of your subform called subformToggle with default value 0.  Then select all paragraphs of the subform, open the text properties dialog and go to the hide tab and enter 'subformToggle=0' for the hide when formula.  You will also have to end your button formula with @Command([RefreshHideFormulas])